# python regex urls

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a bunch of (ugly if I may say) urls, which I would like to clean up using python regex. So, my urls look something like:

```
http://www.thisislink1.com/this/is/sublink1/1
http://www.thisislink2.co.uk/this/is/sublink1s/klinks
http://www.thisislinkd.co/this/is/sublink1/hotlinks/2
http://www.thisislinkf.com.uk/this/is/sublink1d/morelink
http://www.thisislink1.co.in/this/is/sublink1c/mylink
....
```

What I'd like to do is clean up these urls, so that the final link looks like:

```
http://www.thisislink1.com
http://www.thisislink2.co.uk
http://www.thisislinkd.co
http://www.thisislinkf.de
http://www.thisislink1.us
....
```

and I was wondering how I can achieve this in a pythonic way. Sorry if this is a 101 question - I am new to pytho regex structures.

Answer (score 7):

Use [urlparse.urlsplit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlsplit):

```
In [3]: import urlparse    

In [8]: url = urlparse.urlsplit('http://www.thisislink1.com/this/is/sublink1/1')

In [9]: url.netloc
Out[9]: 'www.thisislink1.com'
```

---

In Python3 it would be

```
import urllib.parse as parse
url = parse.urlsplit('http://www.thisislink1.com/this/is/sublink1/1')
```

Answer (score 6):

Why use regex?

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> url = 'http://www.thisislinkd.co/this/is/sublink1/hotlinks/2'
>>> urlparse.urlsplit(url)
SplitResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.thisislinkd.co', path='/this/is/sublink1/hotlinks/2', query='', fragment='')
```

Comment: That is awesome. I did not know about urlparse - very handy I must say. Thanks again. I have accepted your answer. urlparse.urlsplit(url).netloc solved the problem.

Comment: just seen that @unutbu got there first (by a few seconds), go with theirs!

Comment: ok Jon - I will accept unutbu's answer - Thanks again for your help tho!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a URL parser like others have suggested but for completeness here is a solution with regex:

```
import re

url='http://www.thisislink1.com/this/is/sublink1/1'

re.sub('(?<![/:])/.*','',url)

>>> 'http://www.thisislink1.com'
```

Explanation:

Match everything after and including the first forwardslash that is not preceded by a `:` or `/` and replace it with nothing `''`.

```
(?<![/:]) # Negative lookbehind for '/' or ':'
/.*       # Match a / followed by anything
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use something like this:

```
result = re.sub(r"(?m)(http://(www)?\..*?)/", r"\1", subject)
```